# How to disable/remove "Close All Windows" option from taskbar stack?

Tags: windows, winapi, taskbar

I have an application with multiple top-level windows. When the user tries to close a window, they are prompted to exit. If they choose to proceed, then all windows close.

When combining taskbar buttons is enabled, our application windows end up in a stack on the taskbar. If you right-click on the stack on the taskbar, there is an option "Close All Windows". If you click this option, each window gets a `WM_CLOSE`, which causes each window to get the exit prompt.

Is there a way to disable the "Close All Windows" option? There doesn't seem to be a window property for this such as `System.AppUserModel.PreventPinning`.

Alternatively, is there a way to intercept this command for my running application?

There are other options, of course -- our application knows if any exit prompt is displayed, so it could just not display more than one; or we could debounce the WM_CLOSE messages to yield a single event.

Comment: I'm curious to understand why that would be useful to anyone. Would that just make your program harder to use.

Comment: What problem is this attempted "solution" supposed to solve? This should be the question to ask.

Comment: Comments above are obsolete.

Comment: *our application knows if any exit prompt is displayed, so it could just not display more than one* and why not implement this ?

Comment: @RbMm For more context: Typically, our exit prompt is centered in the window where an exit is initiated. If we only display a popup on the first `WM_CLOSE`, I expect it will be unpredictable which window receives it first. Additionally, our UX team is considering displaying the exit prompt center screen in the case of "Close All Windows". Other than debouncing WM_CLOSE, I can't think of a way to have the prompt center-window in the one case (attempt to close a single window) and center-screen in the other case (attempt to close all windows).

Comment: One difference if you look with Spy++ is that with a single window, it gets activated first (receives a `WM_ACTIVATE` message) before the close message is sent. With "Close All" the close message comes without the window being activated. Maybe you could change your behaviour depending on whether the window is active or not when it gets `WM_CLOSE`?

Comment: if set `WH_CALLWNDPROC` you can by `wParam` detect are `WM_CLOSE` was sent by the current thread. in case *close all* - wParam will be 0